# Existence of solution to $3a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ with constraints.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am searching for solutions to the following equation:
$$
3a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \tag{1}
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are distinct positive integers, satisfying
$$
ac = bd.\tag{2}
$$

I have found solutions to $(1)$ via a search (over odd $a$) under the constraint $abcd$ is a square, which is weaker than $(2)$. None of these has satisfied $(2)$ however. As an example the smallest solution I found is
$$
(a,b,c,d) = (637, 361, 481, 925) = (7^2\cdot13, 19^2, 13\cdot 37, 5^2\cdot 37)
$$ 
which doesn't satisfy $(2)$.

My apologies for the vagueness of this question, but I just wondered if anyone could offer some insight on this problem? Perhaps there is a simple proof of impossibility, or a restriction on the variables that means the magnitude of any possible solution must be beyond the scope of my laptop.

I welcome anybody's thoughts on this!

A few of my own:

- By Legendre's three square theorem, solutions to $(1)$ usually exist (always when $a$ is odd), and there are often many solutions, so the problem doesn't feel too restrictive.
- Clearly if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a solution, then so is $(ka, kb, kc, kd)$. The solutions I found went beyond this extension.

Answer (score 2):

There are no integer solutions to
$$ 3\,a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \tag{1} $$ and $$ a\,c = b\,d \tag{2} $$
except $\,|a|\!=\!|b|\!=\!|c|\!=\!|d|.\,$
For equation $(2)$ we have a general solution
$$ a = y\,w,\;\; b = x\,y,\;\; c = x\,z,\;\; d = w\,z. \tag{3} $$
Substituting $(3)$ into $(1)$ we simplify to get
$$ (w^2+x^2)\,z^2 = (3\,w^2-x^2)\,y^2. \tag{4} $$
The solution to $(4)$ is
$$ w^2+x^2 = t\,y^2, \quad 3\,w^2-x^2 = t\,z^2. \tag{5} $$
This corresponds to the [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/)
[elliptic curve 24.a4](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/24/a/4)
$$ y^2 = x^3 - x^2 - 4x + 4 = (x-1)(x-2)(x+2) \tag{6} $$
with rank $0$ and hence has no rational generator.
The only rational solutions are 
$$ (-2,0),\; (0,\pm2),\; (1,0),\; (2,0),\; (4,\pm6). \tag{7} $$
The point $\,(0,2)\,$ of order $4$ and $\,(1,0)\,$ of order 2 generate a subgroup of order $8$.

NOTE: The connection between equaton $(5)$ and equation $(6)$
is contained in my
[WXYZ Project](http://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/wxyz.html). Briefly, define the constants
$$ w_0 = 0, x_0 = y_0 = z_0 = w_1 = 1, \\
 x_1 = 2, y_1 = \sqrt{5}, z_1 = \sqrt{-1}. \tag{8} $$
This determines the four sequences
$\,\{w_n, x_n, y_n, z_n\} \,$ which satisfy
$$ w_n^2+x_n^2=y_n^2,\quad 3\,w_n^2-x_n^2=z_n^2 \tag{9} $$
corresponding to equation $(5)$. The sequence $\,\{w_n\}\,$
is an elliptic divisibility sequence with $j$-invariant
$35152/9$ which can be looked up in LMFDB and the first
curve with that $j$-invariant is equation $(6)$.

NOTE: Both equation $(1)$ and equation $(2)$ are homogeneous
quadrics. The general solution to them involves an elliptic
curve. There should be references to such a transformation
but I don't have one at hand now.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the correspondence between $(5)$ and $(6)$?

Comment: another approach requires integers in $p^4 + 14 p^2 q^2 + q^4 = r^2,$ which has (1,1,4) but I think no others. Might be in Mordell's book, Guy mentions some articles about $x^4 + D x^2 y^2 + y^4 = z^2$